# Windows Translator: "ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'to' must be a valid language

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, translation

Im trying to use Bing Translator...

Already Have a token (I think), but when try to get the translation, the same Error is always poping:

```
"ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'to' must be a valid language\u000d\u000aParameter name: to : ID=5217.V2_Json.Translate.5FEAF805"
```

The next is the url that i am using, and I dont see where the error is...

```
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?
&amp;appId=Bearer%20http%3a%2f%2fschemas.xmlsoap.org%2fws%2f2005%2f05%2fidentity%2fclaims%2fnameidentifier=TranslateHelper000&amp;http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2faccesscontrolservice%2f2010%2f07%2fclaims%2fidentityprovider=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&amp;Audience=http%3a%2f%2fapi.microsofttranslator.com&amp;ExpiresOn=1439307776&amp;Issuer=https%3a%2f%2fdatamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net%2f&amp;HMACSHA256=xGQ7LMehBDHJLY2Xq7jN8PXOhRCYqs%2boUb2V4Ic4XLI%3d
&amp;from=en
&amp;to=pt
&amp;text=Home
&amp;oncomplete=mycallback
```

(pt is defined as language in translator... it doesn't work either with to=en...

My question are, if you could help me on this:
1. Is that a normal Token?
2. Is it is normal, what is wrong with code? (I dont have any more hair to take off...)

This is the code I use to send the url (mycallback isn't being called either):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'getTranslatorToken',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (token) {


        var languageFrom = "en";
        var languageTo = "pt";
        var textToTranslate = "Home";

        var strToken = token["access_token"];
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        //s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=Bearer " + token + "&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&text=" + $('#txtMsg').val();
         s.src = "https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/Translate?&appId=Bearer " + strToken +
            "&from=" + encodeURIComponent(languageFrom) +
            "&to=" + encodeURIComponent(languageTo) +
            "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(textToTranslate) +
            "&oncomplete=mycallback";


        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
        console.log(s)
    }).fail(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("Error:"+xhr.responseText);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        //$("#msg").text('Error');
    });
```

Thank

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: My answer below... It is a working example in my project... it has a -1, probably because people like simple answers to complex problems... wich in same cases can't get...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is answered here (in C#):

[How to translate specific content in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915655/how-to-translate-specific-content-in-website)

Working example here (PHP): http://www.johndimm.com/FunWithSpeech/BingTranslator/