# I have built a multi-page website and have to make it a dual language site which translates everything from english to french, how do I go about this?

Tags: javascript, web, translation, translate

I have built a multi-page website using html, css, bootstrap, jquery and javascript, i have been asked that it be possible for the user to translate it to french and english in reverse. I have never done this before and am unsure how to go about it. I am only building the frontend and the translations are being provided to me, do i need to make json files for each language?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is by using a 3rd party. You can use something that is powered by google translate.[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/HOWTO/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_translate) shows how to use it.

Comment: if you don't like using google translate, you can check out this question that was on stackoverflow that has been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915655/how-to-translate-specific-content-in-website

Answer (score 0):

You may check out https://airbnb.io/polyglot.js/.It is a tiny I18n helper library written in JavaScript,based off of Airbnb’s experience adding I18n functionality to its Backbone.js and Node apps.